# Wierd use of java template methods

Tags: java, templates, generics

I am just playing around with the templates and generics in java. Using template methods, I can define them as templates without actually using the template type in the method signiture. 
But, as the template type is defined at runtime on calling the method, how can it be used?

An example looks like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Playaround {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Playaround p = new Playaround();
        p.doSomething(p);
    }

    public <T> void doSomething(Object thing) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        // What kind of object fit in this list?
        // list.add(...?...)
        System.out.println(list.size());
      } 

}
```

Or, if this isn't useful code at all - why does it compile?

Comment: "What kind of object fit in this list?", objects of type `T`.

Comment: Yup, `p.<String>doSomeThing` would take `String`. But the code you write inside `doSomething` would not be aware of that - so yes, the code is completely useless. But, for example `public <T> List<T> populate(Supplier<List<T>> collectionFactory, Supplier<T> itemFactory, int times)` would not be - can you see why?

Comment: Yes, in this case the arguments would define the kind of T.